# Generate random hex color values in Oracle sql database

Tags: oracle

I'm aware similar questions have been asked, but I can't seem to find something that works. I'm creating a table in oracle database which one column is an ID and the other column's value is a hexadecimal color value. When I created the table I put the datatype for the ID as a number and VARCHAR2 for the color. I just want to know if there is a way to generate random hex color values and update the table so that they can be in the color column. Thanks.

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT TO_CHAR( TRUNC( DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE( 0, 256*256*256 ) ), 'FM0XXXXX' )
FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: @Anika If this or another answer solves your question then you can mark it as accepted with the green tick below the answer's voting buttons indicating that your question is solved. If one or more answers are helpful then you can upvote them.

Answer (score 2):

this should give you a pattern how to do it

```
select 1, to_char(floor(dbms_random.value(0,256)), 'XX') from dual
```

Answer (score 0):

To extend vav's solution to a 6 digit hex value with leading zeroes, you could use this formula:

```
select 1,  lpad(trim(to_char(floor(dbms_random.value(0,16777216)),'XXXXXX')),6,'0')
from dual;
```

Comment: This works but for one element. I want to generate a random hex value in each element within the column of my table. I have  UPDATE colors 
  SET (CT) = (SELECT lpad(trim(to_char(floor(dbms_random.value(0,16777216)),'XXXXXX')),6,'0')
from dual); but for every elemnt in CT column I want a new random hex value to be generated.

Comment: @Anika, if I understand your question, you have several rows in the table and you want a different hex color value in the table for each row? You can use `UPDATE colors SET CT = lpad(trim(to_char(floor(dbms_random.value(0,16777216)),'XXXXXX')),6,'0')` - as long as you already have the correct number of rows in your `colors` table and you want all of them updated. If you want to make 10 new rows in the `colors` table, use something like `INSERT INTO colors ( CT ) SELECT lpad(trim(to_char(floor(dbms_random.value(0,16777216)),'XXXXXX')),6,'0')
FROM dual
CONNECT BY level <= 10;`

Comment: If you want to regenerate colors for a given group of IDs, use something like: `UPDATE colors SET CT = lpad(trim(to_char(floor(dbms_random.value(0,16777216)),'XXXXXX')),6,'0') WHERE my_id_column IN ('an id','another id')`